# Having trouble changing image on imageButton at run time

Tags: android, imagebutton

I'm trying to update the image of an imageButton on run time.  I have a switch statement that checks for an ID passed from another activity.  I know the switch statement is working as the correct ID is passed to the TextView.

I've been searching and see some examples use the ImageView and others use the ImageButton.  As you can see below I've tried both and none work.

XML Layout:

```
    <ImageButton android:visibility="gone" android:id="@+id/imageButton" android:src="@drawable/defaultimage" android:layout_width="97dp" android:layout_height="95dp"></ImageButton>
    <TextView android:visibility="gone" android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></TextView>
```

Java Code:

```
    case 1:{
            // Location 1
            ImageView ImageButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            ImageButton .setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
            ImageButton .setVisibility(0);
            TextView Test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            Test.setVisibility(0);
            Test.setText("ID passed is" + id);
            break;
            }
        case 2:{
            // Location 2
            ImageButton ImageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonGhostCamLocation);
            ImageButton .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2);
            ImageButton .setVisibility(0);

            TextView Test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            Test.setVisibility(0);
            Test.setText("ID passed is" + id);
            break;
```

**UPDATE**

Got it to work!  I just removed the android src from the ImageButton in xml layout and it's working fine now.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: First, you should check Java naming conventions (http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm). `ImageButton ImageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(..)` does not make any sense.

Comment: I changed the name here to make it easier to read... the ImageButton ImageButton is actually ImageButton myImageButtonName.  Sorry about that. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of your code seems correct(unless you have funny things like `ImageButton ImageButton` in your original code). The problem must be somewhere else.

Can you see the button if you remove `android:visibility="gone"` from layout?

Btw instead of:

```
setVisibility(0);
```

use

```
setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

That way it is more readable.

Comment: Thanks for this tip!  I was looking for this. :-)

Answer (score 2):

replace this

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
imageButton .setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
imageButton .setVisibility(0);
```

You are using `ImageButton` in xml and getting it as `ImageView` in Java

Comment: As mentioned I included both here to show what I've done.  Neither switch is working properly.  If I use the ImageButton or the ImageView (as I've seen this suggested in various places).

Answer (score 0):

will not allow to use basic functions like this ImageButton as a variable.
use this code

```
private ImageButton myButton;
```

in onCreate()

```
myButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
```

and this myButton variable in the code.

```
case 1:{
        // Location 1            
        myButton .setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
        my .setVisibility(0);
        TextView Test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Test.setVisibility(0);
        Test.setText("ID passed is" + id);
        break;
        }
    case 2:{
        // Location 2          
        myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2);
        my.setVisibility(0);
        TextView Test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Test.setVisibility(0);
        Test.setText("ID passed is" + id);
        break;
```